# Align one of several <li> to the right?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <div id="menu">
<ul><li><a href="#" class="current">SocialSpot</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
<li>Logout</li>
    </div>
    </ul>
```

I have this in a webpage. I have css aligning them. However I want the logout button to be aligned to the right but on the same bar. How can I do this without having them all aligned to the right?

Comment: What do you mean 'aligning them'?  Are you displaying them all horizontally?

Comment: you can add a class to that li and create a css rule for the class.

Comment: I am using them horizontally yes.

Comment: Creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example will drastically increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSS:

```
ul { overflow:auto; }
li { float:left; }
li:last-child { float:right; }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Rs4Sa/

---

Btw the `:last-child` pseudo-class does not work in IE8 (and below). If you want it to work in those browsers, you will have to assign a class (e.g. `right`) to the Logout LI item, and then:

```
li.right { float:right; }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Rs4Sa/1/

Answer (score 1):

You might want `float: right` on the css for the logout link.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/QAjkP/

You can use an id tag to specify the css properties for that one `<li>` item