# How to position one element at the right side of the parent div?

Tags: html, css, position, nav

I'm making a navigation bar for my website.
The last element of the nav should be on the right side of the parent div. (It's the login button).

[image: navigation bar]

But as you can see the login button sinks a little bid into the body. It should be on the same line as the other buttons. I tried doing `position relative` on the parent div (navUl), and `position absolute` + `right:0` in the element. I also tried float right on the element but they both gave me the same result.

My code so far:

html

```
<body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="nav">
                <img class="logo" src="images/WEBSHOPlogo.png">
                <div class="lining">
                    <ul class="navUl">
                        <a href="index.html"><li class="currentNavLiHome"> <img class="homeButton" src="images/home-icon.png" alt="home"></li></a>
                        <a href="games.html"> <li class="navLi">producten</li></a>
                        <a href="info.html"> <li class="navLi">informatie</li></a>
                        <a href="admin.html"><li class="navLiLogin"> <img class="adminButton" src="images/icon-user.png" alt="admin"></li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

css

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.header {
    background-color: #594f4f;
}

.nav {
    height: 170px;
    width: 1100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.lining {
}

.navUl {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 61px;
    position: relative;   
}

.navLi {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #594f4f;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #45ada8;
    font-family:sans-serif; 
    clear: both; 
}

.currentNavLiHome {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px; 
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline;   
    clear: both;

}

.homeButton{
    width: 20px;
}

.adminButton{
    width: 20px;
}

.navLiLogin {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: white;    
    display: inline;
    float: right;


}

.navUl a {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.loginPosition {
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle so it's easier to debug?

Comment: Yes I can. First time using fiddle, it seems to be different than my outcome. https://jsfiddle.net/n6u307ky/

Comment: This Stack Overflow may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198563/align-one-of-several-li-to-the-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little tough without a working fiddle, but give this a shot.

Updated HTML to put anchor tags inside `<li>` as that is better syntax:

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div class="header">
      <div class="nav">
           <img class="logo" src="images/WEBSHOPlogo.png">
           <div class="lining">
                <ul class="navUl">
                     <li class="currentNavLiHome"><a href="index.html"><img class="homeButton" src="images/home-icon.png" alt="home"></a></li>
                     <li class="navLi"><a href="games.html"> producten</a></li>
                     <li class="navLi"><a href="info.html"> informatie</a></li>
                     <li class="navLiLogin"><a href="admin.html"><img class="adminButton" src="images/icon-user.png" alt="admin"></a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Updated CSS.  Basically we float the `<ul>` and give it a 100% width, then float the `<li>` left, except float the `li:last-child` to the right.  Also, remove the `clear:both` from the `<li>` so they stay inline.

CSS:

```
.nav ul {
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
}
.nav ul li {
     float: left;
}
.nav ul li:last-child {
     float: right;
}

.navLi {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
   margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #594f4f;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #45ada8;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

.currentNavLiHome {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px; 
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `float:right;` in the CSS code. 
 Also I think it would be a god solution if you gave the div which contains links (you may create it) a width of 90% and give the div which contains the login  a width of 10% for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <body>
            <div class="header">
                <div class="nav">
                    <img class="logo" src="images/WEBSHOPlogo.png">
                    <div class="lining" class="login" <!-- give it width="90%" -->>
                        <ul class="navUl">
                            <a href="index.html"><li class="currentNavLiHome"> <img class="homeButton" src="images/home-icon.png" alt="home"></li></a>
                            <a href="games.html"> <li class="navLi">producten</li></a>
                            <a href="info.html"> <li class="navLi">informatie</li></a></ul>

<div class="login" <!-- give it width="10%" --> ><a href="admin.html"> <img class="adminButton" src="images/icon-user.png" alt="admin"></li></a></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Making the first links 90% width and the last that has to be right 10%. Also worked when floating them both, thanks for the help.